# Calculo de fatorial em uma progressão aritmética

Tags: c, algoritmo

Preciso criar um programa que calcule o fatorial iniciado com 2 e ir adicionando mais 2 a cada repetição ate atingir 20 vezes.

Ex: 2!, 4!, 6!, 8!...

Tentei de várias formas, mas toda vez que compilo ele me entrega a primeira resposta do numero fatorado correto, mas as próximas estão todas incorretas.

[image: Código compilado]

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int x = 0;
    int i = 1;
    int fat;


    while(i <= 20){

        x = x + 2;

        for(fat = 1; x > 1; x = x - 1){
            fat = fat * x;
        }


        printf("%d\n", fat);
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

O resultado esperado seria 2, 24, 720, 40320, mas esta dando 2, 6, 6, 6...

Como corrigir isso?

Comment: Em primeiro lugar precisa achar um critério. A progressão mostra claramente não é aritmética. Tendo uma definição clara do que precisa fazer dá para olhar para o código, que é confuso.

Comment: Sugiro que faça o [teste de mesa](/q/220474/112052) para entender o que está acontecendo. Ao final do `for` o valor de `x` será 1, e na próxima iteração do `while`, ele começará em 3 (ou seja, vc está calculando o fatorial de 3 várias vezes). Também não ficou claro se 20! é o maior valor a ser calculado, ou se são 20 termos (o que terminaria a sequência em 40!, um número com mais de 47 dígitos e que causa *overflow* nos resultados)

Comment: Note que você modifica o valor de x dentro de seu comando `for`. Ao sair do loop a variável `x` sempre estará valendo 1.

Comment: Uma dica: não precisa desse `for`. Se a ideia é mostrar 2!, depois 4!, 6! e assim por diante, não precisa calcular tudo desde o início.
Se você já calculou 2!, basta multiplicar por 3 e 4 para obter 4!, depois basta multiplicar por 5 e 6 para obter 6! e assim por diante

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

A lógica é bem complicada, vamos pensar um pouco. Você tem termos que começam em 2 e vão evoluindo de 2 em 2. Então no laço vamos chama isso de `termo` em vez de `i` como chamou para dar mais semântica ao que estamos fazendo já que o laço faz parte do domínio do problema é não é só um mecanismo para varrer uma coleção de dados.

Vamos pular de 2 em 2 já em um `for` que é mais simples que um `while`.

Vamos começar o fatorial onde ele sempre começa que é 1. E vamos aplicar o cálculo dele sempre usando dois passos (dá para fazer em um só mas complica o entendimento).

Antes de achar o fatorial do termo atual precisamos achar o fatorial do termo anterior porque para mostrar pula de 2 em 2, mas para calcular não, tem que calcular todos os fatoriais, afinal o fatorial sempre é baseado no seu fatorial anterior, não pode pular um dos números. Então faço a conta com o termo anterior e logo depois que acha esse eu faço com o atual. E pronto, tenho o fatorial necessário.

Como estou acumulando eu não preciso calcular todos fatoriais novamente, eu já tenho o valor do termo anterior, então é só repetir esse passo. Assim:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int fat = 1;
    for (int termo = 2; termo <= 20; termo += 2) {
        fat *= termo - 1;
        fat *= termo;
        printf("%d\n", fat);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/UrEdC3). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ydqfdjpc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/FactorialAP.c).

Não tenho certeza se deveria terminar em 20, mas se for 20 termos pulando de 2 em 2, e não apenas até o 20o. termo, é só fazer o laço ir até 40.

Answer (score 0):

Muito obrigado pessoal, consegui achar uma forma de resolver graças aos comentários e resposta.

Fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int x = 2;
    int i = 1;
    double fat;
    int aumento1 = 3, aumento2 = 4;

    for(fat = 1; x > 1; x = x - 1){
        fat = fat * x;
    }

    while(i <= 20){

        printf("%lf\n", fat);
        fat = fat * aumento1 * aumento2;
        aumento1 = aumento1 + 2;
        aumento2 = aumento2 + 2;

        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Usei duas variáveis para ir acrescentando +2 a cada repetição que na qual usei para calcular o fatorial, sendo esse caso:

```
        fat = fat * aumento1 * aumento2;
        aumento1 = aumento1 + 2;
        aumento2 = aumento2 + 2;
```

Mais uma vez agradeço, me ajudou bastante!

Não tenho costume aqui então não sei como fechar, ou se tem como eu fechar uma discussão.

Comment: Se pode complicar pra que simplificar!